# Expo React Native App + Redux-Persist: AsyncStorage Problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, asyncstorage, redux-persist

I just started a new *Managed* Expo React Native project (Expo *SDK 35*, React Native *0.5.9*) using `redux-persist@6.0.0` but even a fresh expo project with redux/redux-persist is currently throwing the error below.

---

**Using `AsyncStorage` from `react-native`**,

we get the error:

> redux-persist: config.storage is required. Try using one of the provided storage engines `import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'`

---

**Using `AsyncStorage` from `@react-native-community/async-storage`**,

we get the error:

> [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

---

**Using `storage` from `redux-persist/lib/storage`**,

we get the error:

> console.error: "redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage."

---

**Question:** How do we solve this problem without ejecting? Thanks!

---

**`redux-persist` Code**

*Note: Previous attempts have been commented out:*

```
// Chose 1 of the 3 storages
// import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
// import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import { createMigrate, persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import reducer from "../reducers";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    version: 0,
    storage,    // 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
}

// const persistConfig = {
//   key: 'root',
//   version: 0,
//   AsyncStorage,    // '@react-native-community/async-storage'
// }

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're declaring your `persistConfig` using `@react-native-community/async-storage`?

Comment: @Neeeko I've updated the question (commented out) to answer your question. Thank you!

Comment: Are you having this issue on both devices or iOS only?

Comment: @Neeeko iOS only. No android device currently available for testing this.

Answer (score 7):

This import is for Web App :

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
```

For React Native, you should use the following imports:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { createMigrate, persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import reducer from "../reducers";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    version: 0,
    //...
    storage: AsyncStorage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
```

Comment: Thanks tolotra! I did try your approach (commented out on question) but encountered the error `[@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.` Maybe because I am using Expo SDK 35 which uses React Native 0.5.9 and not 0.6?

Comment: May be, try to use expo import for AsyncStorage `import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';`

Comment: I have tried this approach, encountered the error  `redux-persist: config.storage is required. Try using one of the provided storage engines import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'.` Updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

For React Native below code **does not work**.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    AsyncStorage
}
```

Because `persistConfig` expects a key `storage`

Below `persistConfig` **works** for React Native.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage
}
```

Comment: I'm using expo ~45.0.0. So far, this is the solution that works. `@react-native-community/async-storage` this doesn't work since it can't link up.

Answer (score 1):

A simple inadvertent typo such as

```
import { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

will end up with

`config.storage is required`

or

`redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage.`

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: Simply remove { }

Answer (score 0):

It might be a library linking issue.

Make sure you ran
`react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage`

I would also suggest going to your `ios` folder and running `pod install`.

If you're not using Cocoapods, have a look [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/LEGACY/docs/Linking.md) for manual linking.

Comment: Thanks! Hoping for a solution without having to eject the Expo app (necessary for linking the lib)

Answer (score 0):

1. yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
2. import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
   const authPersistConfig = {
   key: 'auth',
   stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
   storage: AsyncStorage,
   whitelist: ['isAuthenticated', 'sessionToken', 'userId'],
   };

worked for me